# How to get timezone full form "India Standard Time" in php?

Tags: php, date, timezone

I know using `date('T')` will give current timezone of server in abbreviation ex: `IST`. I want full form of it. Ex: "**India Standard Time**" or "**Eastern Standard Time**".. etc. How will i acheive this in `PHP`? Is there any method to do it in `PHP`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), `T` return timezone abbreviation but you need to use `e` that return timezone identifier

Comment: `e`  will return the timezone like `Asia/Kolkatta`. But i need `India Standard Time`

Comment: @SurendarK I think it isn't php full format as you want. Check http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get()
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)